# Nginx проблема при настройке виртуального хоста

Tags: javascript, php, nginx, apache2

Есть конфиг другого сервера

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    listen [::]:8000;

    root /var/www/html/crm;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name crm;

    access_log   /var/www/html/access.log;
    error_log    /var/www/html/error.log;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/crm/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Конфиг основного сервера

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl        on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    autoindex on;
    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;
    location /crm {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что сервер на порте 8000 пытается получить файлы не в папке /crm, а корне:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По идее сайт должен получать файлы
https://site.com/crm/, а не из https://site.com/

Comment: Откуда такой вывод "по идее"? Изображения берутся (или пытаются) взяться из img src, что там прописано - туда и шлют запрос. Если вам нужно сделать rewrite /crm/ в корень /, то это делается иначе.

Comment: а как сделать такой rewrite?

Comment: Смотрите [документацию Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) если хотите сделать через него, либо для [NGINX](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)